# Emulate a slow iPhone

Tags: iphone, performance, simulator

I have an iPhone app (Objective C++). My beta testers - some of them, not all of them - are complaining of slow startup, 7 to 10 seconds. On my device (it's a 3GS), it loads in about 2 sec. On the device simulator - even faster. As things stand now, I cannot even isolate the bottleneck.

Can I somehow slow down the simulator or a fast device? Setting the simulated hardware version to 2.0 does not help.

As a last resort, I could try and borrow an old, slow device from a friend for a night or two. But I'd rather not...

Comment: I doubt there is a 7x performance difference between the slowest and fastest iPhone hardware. Must be some other factor. Have you correlated that all the slow startups come from old iPhones while all the fast startups are from new ones. What about correlating with firmware revisions.

Comment: Never depend on the simulator for performance testing. You can't really compare the hardware on the iPhone with a Mac.

Comment: Good point. Will collect some stats...

Comment: @Tarydon - there may be for certain actions. I've got an OpenGL app that takes about 10 seconds to load images on my 3G, and about 3 seconds on my brother's 3GS. Not 7x, but approx what the OP reported.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I'd try profiling the startup with Shark - it's hard to profile startup on the device, one way is to put a 5-6 second sleep statement in ApplicationDidFinishLaunching so you have time to attach Shark and start recording, don't make it too long though or the app will be killed!

Also consider what you are doing on startup that might be a lot longer for some people - looking at address records, or things like that.

Comment: You should be able to launch the app with Shark so that it starts sampling as soon as the app starts.

Comment: I don't think it is possible, Shark has no way to start a program on an attached phone.  There's an option in XCode to launch the debugger on app start, but nothing as far as I know to launch Shark the same way (and you can't use shark to profile an app the debugger  is attached to, otherwise you could break at start).

Answer (score 1):

Aral Balkan [links](http://aralbalkan.com/2333) to some nice tools by [Mike Shrag](http://mschrag.github.com/) that allow you to get the old slow motion simulation mode on triple shift working in SDK 3.  Speedlimit - which allows you to throttle network bandwidth might be useful.

Comment: Not quite what I'm after... It slows down animations and network access - not performance across the board.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but one option is to use a non-SSD iMac or MBP to test on a slow environment. The latest Xcode versions and simulators (XC version 7 for sure) run *extremely* slowly on non-SSD devices. More slowly than any actual phone...